# Transform array into newline separated string using map.reduce?

Tags: javascript

I think it should be possible to use map.reduce to transform an array into newline separated string. But for some reason it is not working. What am I doing wrong

```
copyLicenseCodesToClipboard = () => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    const licenseCodes = this.props.generateLicenseCodes.reduce((accumulator: any, element: LicenseCode) =>
        accumulator.concat(element.code).concat('\n')
    );
    copyToClipboard(JSON.stringify(licenseCodes));
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: accumulator.concat is not a function

Comment: It looks like you forgot to pass an array as the initial value. On the first iteration, the accumulator will be `this.props.generateLicenseCodes[0]`, which is a `LicenseCode`, not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `map` and `join`, which seems to be more intuitive in this case.

```
const licenseCodes = this.props.generateLicenseCodes.map((element)=>{return element.code;}).join("\n");
```